# How to make content scrollable in flex box so that another box remains with constant width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to construct a flexbox grid so that the width of the left side remains constant while the viewport being resizing. On the other hand, the right side should shrink and its content becomes scrollable.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-content {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.left-side {
  width: 200px;
  flex: initial;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

.right-side {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.inner-content {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-content">
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="right-side">
      <div class="inner-content">
        Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected: `left-side` container should remain 200px wide while `right-side` is shrinking when the width of the viewport becomes less than 800px. The `inner-content` box becomes scrollable when there is no room for its content.

Actual: `left-side` is shrinking when the width of `right-side` reaches to the width of `inner-content`.

Comment: `.left-side { flex: 0 0 200px;}` should do it.

Comment: @kukkuz's answer is quite good (and should be accepted, IMHO). Here's an alternative: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zgfeo8mp/. Unlike him, I was lazy and didn't mark out what I removed/added, so you'll need to go through it line by line and see the differences. I added it as I thought it might help in your quest to master CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            min-width: 200px; /*nhannt210695 left-side width = 200px. [left-side=200px] |<- limit */
        }

        .flex-content {
            display: flex;
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-content: stretch;
            background-color: cadetblue;
        }

        .left-side {
            width: 200px; 
            flex: initial;
            background-color: darkcyan;
        }

        .right-side {
            flex: 1;
            background-color: bisque;
            width: 0px; /* nhannt210695 string "Abcd..." on the right */
        }

        .inner-content {
            background-color: aquamarine;
            overflow: auto; /* nhannt210695 auto overflow of text*/
        }
    </style>
    <title>How to make content scrollable in flex box so that another box remains with constant width</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-content">
            <div class="left-side"></div>
            <div class="right-side">
            <!-- Tip: delete div of inner-content and change screen -->
                <div class="inner-content">
                    Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please consider adding a short description about how this works.

Comment: ".flex-container" contains "left-side" and "right-side". Since "right-side" must have a constant width, the minimum "flex-container" limit should be set to 200px. Leave the string "Abcd ..." on the right to set the width of "right-side" to 0px. Doing so "right-side" will not override "left-side" when changing the screen size. The DIV size contains the string "Abcd ..." that will not depend on its content, but depends on the parent tag as "flex-content".

Comment: great! it would be best if you add this to your answer so everyone can see it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting `width: 200px` you can set `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to zero for the `left-content` and then set `flex-basis` to 200px

- the flex shorthand would be `flex: 0 0 200px`,
- make your `right-section` a *flexbox* too (and optionally align it along the *cross-axis* to the start using `align-items: flex-start`),
- add `min-width: 0` to the `right-section` so that it overrides the default `min-width: auto` - now it will be able to shrink beyond its contents,
- also add `overflow: auto` to the `inner-content` (and `width: 100%` if you need the `inner-content` to fill the horizontal space).

See demo below (also removed some redundant / unwanted styles):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-content {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  /*justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;*/
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.left-side {
  /* width: 200px;
  flex: initial; */
  flex: 0 0 200px;  /* added */
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

.right-side {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: flex; /* added */
  align-items: flex-start; /* added */
  min-width: 0; /* added */
}

.inner-content {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 100%; /* if needed */
  overflow: auto; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-content">
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="right-side">
      <div class="inner-content">
        Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I want. This code makes the whole `right-side` be scrollable. I expect the nested `inner-content` to be scrollable and `right-side` just shrinks.

Comment: @AndreiKovalev see the updated answer, thank you :)